# SQL - multiple select statement (General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select
asr.level_id,
IFNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN c.school_id = '".$school_id."' THEN asr.avg END),0) AS school_average,
IFNULL(AVG(CASE WHEN c.school_id != '".$school_id."' THEN asr.avg END),0) AS other_school_average,
IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.school_id = '".$school_id."' and asr.avg >= AVG(CASE WHEN c.school_id != '".$school_id."' THEN asr.avg END)) THEN asr.avg END),0) AS school_count,
IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN c.school_id != '".$school_id."' THEN asr.avg END),0) AS other_school_count

from assessment_report asr
left join challenge c on c.user_id = asr.user_id
where asr.assessment_id = '".$assessment_id."' 
and c.status != 'D' and c.assessment_id = '".$assessment_id."'
group by asr.level_id
```

above is my code, the error code appear when i tried to add this line :

```
IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.school_id = '".$school_id."' and asr.avg >= AVG(CASE WHEN c.school_id != '".$school_id."' THEN asr.avg END)) THEN asr.avg END),0) AS school_count,
```

what i am trying to do is : use `other_school_average` data to check the count in my database .

any idea why the error appear ?

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use prepared statements instead

Comment: @mousetail noted on this , will modify my code . btw , do you have any idea on my issue ? was stucked on this part

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh mysql , currently running in localhost

Comment: You can't nest aggregation functions.